# Backbone.js Inherit Views

Tags: view, backbone.js, inheritance

I have a FormView which handles such events as save and cancel.  I also have an AjaxFormView that handles save, cancel and get form by ajax.  I have an AssetFormView that handles save, cancel, get by ajax, delete, and print.
So on and so forth.  there is considerable repitition.

I found a post this post http://kalimotxocoding.blogspot.com/2011/03/playing-with-backbonejs-views.html

where he shows you can extend views.  However, I'm finding that when i have multiple versions of views on the page there are properties cross pollinating.  Is there no built in way to inherit views in backbone, that is safe?

Thanks,

Raif

*** hmmm well, this stuff is pretty thick and my current cross pollination issue may be ( probably is )  the result of some error on my part, but the question still stands, is there not and would it not be an important feature to have, some way to inherit views?

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific about your problem to get a useful answer: show some code, say what you expect, and say what your problem is. Backbone's `extend` function is the main inheritance mechanism, as demonstrated in the post you link to - what's not working?

Comment: Yes, as is often the case I get very very frustrated and finally fire off a question to stackoverflow only to find that either I've made an error or I've found a solution moments later.  As I can not retract questions, hopefully this will server as a pointer to the nice article on the subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd like to see what you mean when you say that your properties are cross-pollenating.

The `View.extend` mechanism works quite well.  Do be aware, though, that you are extending one prototype with new functions.  With prototypical inheritance, the prototype shares it's objects with the new instances.

I am guessing that when you say that your properties are "cross-pollenating", you are actually doing something like this:

```
var baseModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        foo: { bar: "baz" }
    }
});
```

Since the objects are shared, every instance of `baseModel` ends up having the same object for `foo`, giving the feeling of cross-pollination.

If instead, you define your defaults as a function, then each instance will get it's own copy of the `foo` object and your cross-pollination goes away.

```
var baseModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: function() { return {
        foo: { bar: "baz" }
    } }
});
```

Of course, without code, we can't be certain to what your problem is.  Just know that this mechanism has been well-used among the community without trouble.  It is safe.  You just need to understand what is going on.

Comment: Ok so what your saying is that if I do Backbone.Model.extend({ myProperty: "hello" })  Then myProperty will essentially be a static property and if I define it as such Backbone.Model.extend({ myProperty: function(){ "hello" } }) it will be an instance property and unique with each instance?  if this is so it would freakin explain a @#$#@ lot.  I guess I would have to access all my properties as functions but that's a small price to pay for understanding what the @#$3 is going on.  Thank you very much for this info and your conformation of the facts if you see this.

Comment: hmm this doesn't quite seem to be working.  What I'm trying to do is to put object collections on each instance to keep track of child views that I'm creating inside of the parent view. What's happening is that I'm getting the object back but when I set a property on the object it does not "stick".  This may not prove to be a very good pattern anyway, but I would like to be able to do it for now.  I will try a few things and report back if I figure it out.

Comment: ok I posted a new topic showing what I'm doing and asking if I'm crazy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7838926/does-this-seem-like-the-best-proper-way-to-do-backbone-js-view-inheritance

Comment: No, the function vs property swap-out only works for the `defaults` property of the Model.  Backbone just checks to see if it is a function and calls it or else uses the data directly.  See: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-18

Comment: whooow that's an incredible document!  I mean I've been reading the code and following it but this is so much easier!  Thanks for that link!  As per the situation, I'm actually working with views rather then models so I basically did the same thing ( although they are doing it more elegantly and I might follow suite ).  see the link in the above comment. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the same problem you're having but I wanted to have some events defined in the parent class and then have the child class extend the property without overriding it.

If I did it like this, I was overriding what the parent defined:

```
App.parent = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        'click #button-add': 'onAddButtonClicked'
        'click #button-delete': 'onDeleteButtonClicked'
    }

    onAddButtonClicked: function() {
        console.log('onAddButtonClicked');
    },

    onDeleteButtonClicked: function() {
        console.log('onDeleteButtonClicked');
    }
});

App.child = App.parent.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        // This looks redundant but it seems to protect App.parent::events
        this.events = _.extend({}, this.additionalEvents, this.events);

        // THIS IS WRONG and results in errors when I have multiple childdren:
        _.extend(this.events, this.additionalEvents); // <-- this seems to change the parent
    }

    additionalEvents: {
        'click #button-additional': 'onOtherButtonClicked'
    },

    onOtherButtonClicked: function() {
        console.log('child:onOtherButtonClicked');
    }
});
```

When extending the parent's events like this:

```
_.extend(this.events, this.additionalEvents);
```

I'd get **"Uncaught Error: Method 'onOtherButtonClicked' does not exist"** because I was modifying App.parent's events field. `App.child2` was blowing up because it couldn't see the events that were put there by `App.child`.

By changing it to:

```
this.events = _.extend({}, this.additionalEvents, this.events);
```

I was able to protect the parent.