# Does this seem like the best/proper way to do backbone.js view inheritance

Tags: inheritance, view, backbone.js

this is sort of a follow up of this question that i asked

[Backbone.js Inherit Views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7691022/backbone-js-inherit-views)

but it got kind of messy and now I have a solution I would just like someone to tell me if I'm crazy

what I'm doing is as follows:

```
dci.Controller = Backbone.View.extend({
defaults:function(){
    return {
        views:{},
        modules:{},
        isDestroyed:false,
        destroy:function(){
            if(this.isDestroyed){return;}
            this.isDestroyed = true;
            $.each(this.views,function(i,item){
                item.remove();
            });
            $.each(this.modules,function(i,item){
                item.destroy();
            });
        }
    }
}

});
```

then I do this to use the controller:

```
dci.AssetController  = dci.Controller.extend({
events:_.extend({ 
    // whatever events here
}, dci.Controller.prototype.events),

initialize:function(options){
    $.extend(this,this.defaults());
}
});
```

finally i instantiate as follows:

```
var controller = new dci.AssetController(someOptions);
```

so now on my controller var I have a collection of views and modules that are unique per instance so if I have two dci.AssetCotrollers for some reason ( actually I'm using the same model for modules and this is when you have multiple instances of the same class ) they each have there own collection of views and modules.

this was killing me for a while but I think this will work and I particularly would like to thank Brian Genisio who got me on this track in the above mentioned like.

Now please tell me if this is a crazy pattern.
Thanks,
Raif

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are creating a new base view, you should probably stick with View terminology, not Controllers that were previously in backend.. that might confuse someone.

Secondly, I don't see how you are setting `isDestroyed`.

In general, making hierarchical views sounds good to me (i kept doing it manually so far). Not sure how you use modules variable though. Otherwise, in non-wrapper views I think that is too much extra initialization code.

Comment: The isDestroyed flag is set when you call Destroy on the view ( a few lines down ). Modules I use in situations that are often repeated but require more then one "class" or "view"  for instance an Ajax form put in a jquery popup.  I have a view for both of those I create a module that takes a url ( for the ajax ), and a set of buttons with corresponding functions.  I then create both views.  This is not somthing that would be high level like a controller. A controller might have one of these modules, a main view, and a gridview all of which it controlls.